# Animating a javascript counter-balancing mouse reactive overflow... thing

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I'm trying to make a generic widget which can be used to 'counter scroll' overflow content onmouseover/mouse move.
[image]
All fine and well, I've knocked this up here for you to see an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/qR5ra/1/

The problem comes when trying to add 'easing' to the counteraction/ repositioning. NOTE: I cannot use jQuery or any other toolkit here must be real/raw JS.

I've tried a couple of things all produce very scrappy results. Can anyone think of a lean mean easing out solution for this?

EDIT: Ideally something that is cross browser and low overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this for the benefits of anyone else with the same question/problem.

In the end, the best, simplest cross-browser solution without any jQuery nonsense was simply to run a javascript loop with a timer. here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4YeX9/1/

the basis of the code came from a really helpful blog post here:
http://shiriru.blogspot.com/2007/09/javascript-animation-simple-easing.html

hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure JQuery uses the same method (albeit with a lot more code), but I'm not positive. Glad you found something that worked out though.

Answer (score 1):

You could add some css transition properties to smooth out the div's movement.
Just a thought though; your code actually looks pretty good as it is.

```
body
{
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.box{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:grey;
    opacity:0.4;
    border: 2px dotted blue;
    -webkit-transition:left 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:left 0.5s;
    -o-transition:left 0.5s;
    transition:left 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: ive got to stay cross browser compatible. thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 0):

`<shill>`

I released a super simple value tweening/curving library: http://squeegy.github.com/TweenCurve/

It works purely on numbers, no DOM bindingsor built in timers.  It might be simple and flexible enough for you to use.

Comment: does look nice, I'm kinda looking for something which would be 2-3 lines of code and for the timers too. perhaps i can apply one of the penner equations from your nice lib though :-)